# How to choose variables of specific form

Tags: variable

I am trying to work on a problem with a probability distribution. I wanted to get the result in analytical form. 
Suppose I need to keep p1, p2, p3, p4 variables such that p1+p2+p3+p4=1;

How to use this information (p1+p2+p3+p4=1) in mathematica so that wherever in my calculation this term appears, it takes the value 1. Otherwise I will have to find this expression in a lengthy result and convert.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use explicit assumptions:

```
Assuming[p1 + p2 + p3 + p4 == 1, Simplify[Exp[p1 + p2 + 3 p3 + p4 + 3]]]

(* Out: E^(4 + 2 p3) *)
```

Comment: okay, it works. Thanks

Comment: @KunalSharma One can also set `$Assumptions = p1 + p2 + p3 + p4 == 1`.  It is equivalent to `Assuming`, except that `Assuming` temporarily sets `$Assumptions` and setting  `$Assumptions` will remain in effect for computations until it is reset (`$Assumptions = True`).  Sometimes one form (`Assuming` vs `$Assumptions`) is more convenient than the other.  Also note that only some functions, such as `Simplify`, use `$Assumptions`.

Comment: @KunalSharma if the solution I proposed worked for you, you might consider accepting my answer. You can do so by clicking on the checkmark next to it in the left margin. Thank you!